# How to decompose linear function of several variables to partial effects if changes are large?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

- Suppose we have linear function of two variables: z=f(x,y)
- For simplicity lets take the form: z=x*y (coud be with more variables)
- If both x and y change by significant amount x->x1 and y->y1 then z->z1=x1*y1
- How can we express the total change of z (z-z1) as a sum of partial changes due to x and y?
- Since the formula for total derivative is approximation for small changes, what decomposition should be used when changes are large?
- Is there a generic decomposition, at least for linear functions?
- Is there a general approach for calculating what % of the change in z is due to the change in x and what is due to the change in y?

Comment: With a function this simple you can just expand it all out explicitly: if we write $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ for the changes then $\Delta z = (x + \Delta x)(y + \Delta y) - xy = (\Delta x) y + x (\Delta y) + (\Delta x)(\Delta y)$. The first two terms are the linear approximation you get from the derivative and the third term is the error you can't ignore if the change is large.

Comment: In that case it is easy to expand by hand but is there a general approach for calculating what % of the change in z is due to the change in x and what is due to the change in y?

Comment: In general it will just be complicated (you can try a more complicated polynomial to see this, say $z = x^3 y^3$). Already with a term like $(\Delta x)(\Delta y)$ it doesn't obviously make sense to say which part of the change is due to $x$ and which is due to $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but as specified it is only about linear functions.

Comment: You mean bilinear functions? That case is basically the same as this case. And in any case the point about $(\Delta x)(\Delta y)$ still stands. In the extreme case where the initial values are $x = y = 0$ this is the only contributing term.